# pager in custom controls

Tags: xpages

I've got two custom controls. One for the table itself (cc-table), and one with 4 pager-controls around the table (cc-pager, 2 Pager, 1 Pager Expand / Collapse, 1 Pager Sizes) with an editable area. I've combined the two cc's in a xpage and when I preview it on the web it looks fine. Even clicking on the pager works and the viewpanel (cc-table) gets updated, but the pager-control itself is not getting updated. F.eg. in the standard pager-control: When I click on "next", the "two" should change to grey text and the "one" should change to a clickable link. In my case the pager keeps unchanged, so that I cannot move back to first page.

edit: the custom control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/custom.css"></xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
<xp:panel>
    <xp:table style="width:100%">
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
            <xp:div style="text-align:left" styleClass="viewCtrlLeft">
                <xe:pagerExpand id="pagerExpand1"
                    collapseText="Alle Komprimieren" expandText="Alle Erweitern"
                    for="viewPanel1">
                </xe:pagerExpand>
            </xp:div>
            </xp:td>

            <xp:td>
            <xp:div style="text-align:right" styleClass="viewCtrlRight">
                <xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next"
                    partialRefresh="true" id="pager1" for="viewPanel1">
                </xp:pager>
            </xp:div>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table>
</xp:panel>
<xp:panel>
    <xp:callback facetName="facet_1" id="callback1"></xp:callback>
</xp:panel>
<xp:panel>
    <xp:table style="width:100%">
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
            <xp:div style="text-align:left" styleClass="viewCtrlLeft">
                <xe:pagerSizes id="pagerSizes1" for="viewPanel1"></xe:pagerSizes>
            </xp:div>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
            <xp:div style="text-align:right" styleClass="viewCtrlRight">
                <xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next"
                    partialRefresh="true" id="pager2" for="viewPanel1">
                </xp:pager>
            </xp:div>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table>
</xp:panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the partialRefresh="false" and it will begin to refresh the pager along with the view itself.

Original Response...

Is the pager a facet of the viewpanel?  In cases when I've used a pager with a repeat or data table, I've seen this behavior when I've forgotten to set the *for* property of the pager.

```
<xp:pager
    partialRefresh="true"
    layout="Previous Group Next"
    id="pager1"
    style="text-align:right"
    for="rptRules">
</xp:pager>
```

Can you post the code so we can see it for ourselves?

Comment: yes, the pager is for the viewpanel. the "for" is set. I've added the code for the custom control to my first posting.

Comment: Ah, I see it now.  Set the partialRefresh="false" and it will begin to refresh the pager along with the view itself.